# How to "paint" outside the model

Tags: shaders, transparency, texture-painting

What I want is something like this:
[image: Reference Image]

And by trying some things, I made something similar by duplicating the model and scale it a little bigger.
[image: What I made]

[image: Shader1]

[image: Shader2]

But as you can see, there are some problems with what I made. First the color difference, also the outline doesn't appear in front of the painted texture. And another problem is that there are some places where it doesn't appear correctly, the ear for example.[image: Example]

**Is there a way to achieve something similar? Or because the 3D limitations it's not possible to make a effect as if you painted outside the lineart?**

Comment: Is the effect of the offset linework in animation constant on the offset distance, or is it slightly changing? I would consider animation of the characters and the linework separate and recombine them in the Compositor.

Comment: Is the effect of the offset linework in animation constant on the offset distance, or is it slightly changing? I would consider animation of the characters and the linework separate and recombine them in the Compositor.

Comment: @CraigDJones It changes a little, but I'm not planning to animate it so it would be okay with the same offset.
How can I do the thing you say with the compositor? I use solidify modifier to do the outline, in case that's important to know.

Comment: You might try the copy of the main object and use a holdout shader to get the transparency, render that as a separate layer and alpha over to your main image.